# How can I fetch the answers posted in last week based on tags of the question?

Tags: support, api, tags, answers

I see that tags are present only for questions. How can I get the answers to these questions given in last week (if any) having specific tags?

Answer (score 1):

I'd still use the [/questions method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions), and change the [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) to include answer details. E.g. [this query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=support&filter=!-*jbN-(0_ynL&site=stackapps&run=true) lists all Stack Apps answers in the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag, newest first. All I had to do was to edit the default filter and check the checkboxes for the fields 'answer' → 'body' and 'question' → 'answers'.

There is no way to filter on answer date upfront, but if you sort by question activity, you can ignore older answers and stop searching when you see a question with a `last_activity_date` older than a week ago.

[image]

An alternative would be to use the [/search/excerpts method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#fromdate=2020-04-14&order=desc&sort=activity&q=is%3Aa&tagged=support&filter=default&site=stackapps&run=true). This seems to work too, but it doesn't return the full body, so if you need that, you'll need to make another call to e.g. [/answers/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids).

[image]

Comment: This is giving answers only for the questions asked since last week. Is there any way we can get the answers which were updated/added last week for the questions posted earlier.

Comment: Check, you're right. I've modified the solution (which does require some filtering on the client side) and found an alternative as well.